# Montrer sa colère dans la défense d'une cause noble

Tags: grammaire

Je me demandais s'il n'y avait pas un mot pour nommer le fait d'exprimer sa colère d'une certaine façon dans la défense d'une cause noble, du genre qui implique la  défense d'un pays colonisé où d'un pays en guerre, où des personnes sur la planète terre qui n'ont ni nourriture ni eau, par exemple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de mots mais il y a des expressions qui expriment des degrés variés d'implication ; on dit plus souvent « [une noble cause](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une+cause+noble%2Cune+noble+cause&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20cause%20noble%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20noble%20cause%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cune%20cause%20noble%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20noble%20cause%3B%2Cc0) » mais « cause noble » s'utilise aussi.

Les expressions suivantes sont presque toutes tirées de [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/noble+cause.html) mais je les ai triées dans un certain ordre et j'ai ajouté quelques annotations. Il ne fait nul doute qu'il s'en trouve d'autres.

**I** *expressions qui dénotent un engagement*

- s'attacher à une noble cause : *engagement au moins sur le plan des principes*
- s'associer à une noble cause : *engagement au moins sur le plan des principes*
- s'engager pour une noble cause : *engagement qui peut être plus important, véritable action*
- se mettre au service d'une noble cause : *engagement complet*

**II** *expressions qui dénotent la forme de l'activité après un engagement*

- servir une noble cause : *activité normale*
- croire et s'investir dans une noble cause  : *activité normale*
- lutter/se battre pour une noble cause : *activité normale*
- mettre son temps et ses compétences au service d'une noble cause : *insiste sur le don de soi*
- collaborer/contribuer à une noble cause : *activité normale*
- œuvrer en faveur d'une noble cause : *activité normale*
- manifester pour une noble cause : *activité normale*
- vivre pour une noble cause : *activité extrême*
- se sacrifier pour une noble cause : *activité extrême qui peut aller jusqu'à la mort*
- mourir pour une noble cause  : *activité la plus extrême ou conséquence de l'activité*

Quelqu'un peut par exemple s'attacher à une noble cause et ne faire que manifester pour cette cause.